# Amplifying states using partial information

Tags: measurement, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

Assume we have an initial state $(H^{\otimes n}|0\rangle)|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}|i\rangle|0\rangle$ in two $n$-qubit registers (let $N=2^n$). Then we feed this state through a massive unitary gate $U_f$ to get $$|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}|i\rangle|f(i)\rangle . $$
My goal is that I want to measure any one of the states in the first register for which the second register is the zero-state, or put differently, I am looking for any $i$, where $f(i)=0$.
As a peculiarity, I know exactly how many states there are for which $f(i)$ vanishes, but I do not know which ones, so I basically know the amplitude of the state
$$\sum_{i=0,\dots,N-1\atop f(i)=0}|i\rangle|0\rangle . $$
If it helps, the amplitude scales with $N^{-1/4}$, and is notably bigger than the amplitude of any other state.

I believe that the best way to measure a desired state is to increase the amplitudes of the states, where the second register is $|0\rangle$ and then to measure the second register, so that the wave function collapses into a superposition of wanted results.

My question now is, how can I increase the probability of measuring $|0\rangle$ in the second register? In particular, I am looking for fast way to do this (ideally in polynomial time) and was hoping that the extra information about the amplitude of the desired state is somehow relevant in increasing this amplitude in a well-directed way.

Here's what I considered so far:

I know that one of the possibilities is to use Grover's amplitude amplification, but first of all, Grover will probably be too slow for large enough $n$. But I am not sure if I have a big advantage that my desired state already has a higher amplitude than any other state, and that I therefore would need to perform Grover only a few times. Further, Grover needs equal superposition states, so I would need to use my unitary matrix $U_f$ multiple times (if I understood [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23753/using-grover-on-entangled-states) correctly). I would rather prefer to not use this multiple times, as I assume this operation to also be computationally heavy, or that I only have black-box access to it.

I have also tried to use simple rotation matrices on the second register, but this never worked as I seem to add new states that weren't there before (states that had amplitude zero before). I guess this has something to do with the entanglement between both states, and that I would have to co-rotate the first register in a coherent fashion, so maybe there might be a way to do this in a more constructive way, but I really do not know where to begin and I expect to need to use $U_f$ again.

I have also read about POVM-filtering, but haven't really understood how I can use this to tackle my problem. I also believe that this would lead to similar problems as with the rotation matrices.

Just to give you an example of how my states look like, here's an example with 3 qubits. After $U_f$, I end up with
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\left[ \Big(|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|011\rangle+|100\rangle\Big)|000\rangle + \Big(|000\rangle+|111\rangle\Big)|100\rangle+|101\rangle|001\rangle+|110\rangle|011\rangle \right],$$
so my probability is now $1/2$ to measure $|000\rangle$ in the second register. Obviously this is not a bad probability, but for larger $n$ it becomes much smaller.

Thank you for any help or leads!